# Derivative of $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ using the limit definition.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I just started learning Calculus on my own and understand where $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ comes from, but I'm having trouble with this one; I think my Algebra skills are letting me down.

I start with $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \left(\left(\frac{x+h}{1+(x+h)^2} - \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\right) \frac{1}{h} \right)$ but then get lost expanding everything. I don't see how to end up with $h$ as a factor in the numerator so that I can get rid of the denominator.

Comment: Do you want to find the derivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ or $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: @Paul, thanks for pointing that out, I edited it.

Comment: Note that your difference quotient is not written quite correctly.  You can edit the question to put the $\cdot \frac{1}{h}$ *outside* of the parentheses.  The difference $f(x + h) - f(x)$ is all divided by $h$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**.
$$\eqalign{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
  &=\Bigl(\frac{x+h}{1+(x+h)^2}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\Bigr)\frac{1}{h}\cr
  &=\frac{(x+h)(1+x^2)-x(1+(x+h)^2)}{h(1+x^2)(1+(x+h)^2)}\cr
  &=\frac{1+x^2-2x^2-hx}{(1+x^2)(1+(x+h)^2)}\cr}$$
and now it is easy to take $h\to0$.

Comment: thanks. It was actually for x/(1+x^2), sorry for the mistake. This is helpful too though, I need all the insight I can get about this material.

Comment: Just saw that.  Revised answer quickly, hope it is correct.

Comment: why isn't f(x+h) = (x+h)/(1 + (x+h)^2) instead?

Comment: Is $f(x)$ supposed to be $x/(1+x)^2$ or $x/(1+x^2)$?  The title of your question looks like it's the former, so $f(x+h)$ would be $(x+h)/(1+x+h)^2$.